# Literate Programming with non org-mode Collaborators

Tags: org-mode, literate-programming

I've been starting to take a literate programming approach using org-mode for school assignments.  However a lot of assignments require working in a group with other students who typically don't have emacs/org-mode experience.

The only solution I can think of so far is to create an 'id' for each section in my source code and use the search link method [here](http://orgmode.org/manual/Search-options.html#Search-options) to link my org file to each section.  For example:

code.py

```
# Section1
```

code.org

```
* [[file:code.py::Section1][Section 1]]
```

The biggest issue I see with this is others won't benefit from the information in my org file.

I'm hoping for advice on either:

- How best to implement a system using links as described above
- A different approach others have used to solve the same issue

Comment: IPython seems to have a lower barrier of entry. You can interface to the notebook with `ein`: https://github.com/tkf/emacs-ipython-notebook

Comment: That could work, my first hesitation would be that IPython doesn't do well with Git but I guess you can export the code and commit that as well to get a good idea of what's changed.  Ideally I'd like to keep things in `org-mode` but I'll look into `ein`, thanks

Comment: Check out this org-mode -> jupyter notebook exporter: http://kitchingroup.cheme.cmu.edu/blog/2017/01/21/Exporting-org-mode-to-Jupyter-notebooks/